# Facebook API Instagram webhook not firing

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, facebook-webhooks

I am having trouble testing Facebook API's Instagram webhooks

Here is what I've done :

- My Facebook application is validated with `manage_pages`, `instagram_manage_insights` and `instagram_basic` permissions
- My Facebook application is "Live"
- I have subscribed my app to my Facebook page POSTing on `subscribed_apps` endpoint (explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/webhooks/#install-app ). I already use the "feed" field. GETing `subscribed_apps` endpoint give the following result:

```
# v6.0/{my-page-id}/subscribed_apps?fields=subscribed_fields

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "{my-app-id}",
      "subscribed_fields": [
        "feed" // the missing "instagram" here seems normal as it is not handled by API
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Using ngrok I am trying to test the webhook on my local machine. I correctly receive the "test" data (using app dashboard button) but nothing happen when I subscribe to the webhook

I don't understand what I am missing here. The `feed` webhook I also subscribed too, works perfectly.

### UPDATE

I managed to recieve the "story_insights" hooks, so I guess my configuration is OK. But I still don’t get any incoming comment or mention. Are thesi features still available in new graph api versions ?

Comment: And your page is connected to an Instagram Business or Creator Account as well?

Comment: yes, this is a business account

Comment: I have the same issue. Subscribed to the webhook, all is working, test data comes through but no insights ever sent after a story expires. 
Strange thing, there are no insights in the Instagram app either when I check the story after it expired.

Comment: @42droidsLtd I assumed Facebook stopped providing these data but haven't updated their documentation. My hook is up and running since 2 month ago but still nothing fired it. :( Please let me know if you have any luck understanding what is happening here.

Comment: @benomite Check out https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started/webhooks-for-instagram/#install-app You have to subscribe each user after they authenticate to get the insights.
You will need the "page token" for the Facebook page which belongs to the IG account.
Use 'feed' as 'subscribed_fields' as IG does not have it's own fields (but we have to use one) If response is success you are done. Happy to explain more if doesn't work.